# Can and do compilers convert recursive logic to equivalent non-recursive logic?

Tags: programming-languages, compiler, recursion

I've been learning F# and it's starting to influence how I think when I'm programming C#. To that end, I have been using recursion when I feel the result improves readability and I can't envision it winding out to a stack overflow.

This leads me to ask whether or not compilers could automatically convert recursive functions to an equivalent non-recursive form?

Comment: tail call optimization is a good if basic example but that only works if you have `return recursecall(args);` for the recursion, the more complex stuff is possible by creating an explicit stack and winding it down, but I doubt they will

Comment: @ratchet freak: Recursion does not mean "computation that is using a stack".

Comment: @Giorgio I know but a stack is the easiest way to convert recursion to a loop

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, some languages and complilers will convert recursive logic to non-recursive logic.  This is known as [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) - note that not all recursive calls are tail call optimizible.  In this situation, the compiler recognizes a function of the form:

```
int foo(n) {
  ...
  return bar(n);
}
```

Here, the language is able to recognize that the result being returned is the result from another function and change a function call with a new stack frame into a jump.

Realize that the classic factorial method:

```
int factorial(n) {
  if(n == 0) return 1;
  if(n == 1) return 1;
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

is **not** tail call optimizatable because of the inspection necessary on the return.

To make this tail call optimizeable,

```
int _fact(int n, int acc) {
    if(n == 1) return acc;
    return _fact(n - 1, acc * n);
}

int factorial(int n) {
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    return _fact(n, 1);
}
```

Compiling this code with `gcc -O2 -S fact.c` (the -O2 is necessary to enable the optimization in the compiler, but with more optimizations of -O3 it gets hard for a human to read...)

```
_fact:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        cmpl    $1, %edi
        movl    %esi, %eax
        je      .L2
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        imull   %edi, %eax
        subl    $1, %edi
        cmpl    $1, %edi
        jne     .L4
.L2:
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

One can see in segment `.L4`, the `jne` rather than a `call` (which does a subroutine call with a new stack frame).

Please note this was done with C.  Tail call optimization in java is hard and depends on the JVM implementation -- [tail-recursion + java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail-recursion+java) and [tail-recursion + optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tail-recursion+optimization) are good tag sets to browse.  You may find other JVM languages are able to optimize tail recursion better (try clojure (which requires the [recur](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157684/what-limitations-does-the-jvm-impose-on-tail-call-optimization) to tail call optimize), or scala).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP is asking.  Just because the runtime does or doesn't consume stack space in a certain way, doesn't mean the function isn't recursive.

Comment: @MattFenwick How do you mean? "This leads me to ask whether or not compilers could automatically convert recursive functions to an equivalent non-recursive form" - the answer is "yes under certain conditions".  The conditions are demonstrated, and there are some gotcha's in certain other popular languages with tail call optimizations that I mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

Tread carefully.

The answer is yes, but not always, and not all of them. This is a technique that goes by a few different names, but you can find some pretty definitive information [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailCallOptimization) and at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

I prefer the name "Tail Call Optimization" but there's others and some people will confuse the term.

That said there are a couple important things to realize:

- To optimize a tail call, the tail call requires parameters that are known at the time the call is made. That means  if one of the parameters is a call to the function itself, then it *cannot* be converted into a loop, because this would require arbitrary nesting of said loop which cannot be expanded at compile time.
- C# does *not* reliably optimize tail calls. The IL has the instruction to do so which the F# compiler will emit, but the C# compiler will emit it inconsistently, and depending on the JIT situation, the JIT may or may not do it at all. **All indications are you should not rely on your tail calls being optimized in C#, the risk of overflow in doing so is significant and real**

Comment: Are you sure that this is what the OP is asking?  As I posted under the other answer, just because the runtime does or doesn't consume stack space in a certain way, doesn't mean the function isn't recursive.

Comment: @MattFenwick that's actually a great point, in real terms it depends, The F# compiler emitting tail call instructions is maintaining the recursive logic completely, it's just instructing the JIT to execute it in a stack-space-replacing fashion rather than stack-space-growing, however other compilers may literally compile to a loop. (Technically the JIT is compiling to a loop or possibly even loopless fashion if the loop is total up front)